# firefox can't the server at start.unbuntu.com

Tags: networking

I just got a used laptop running Ubuntu 14.1.  Problem is trying to launch Firefox which cannot seem to find the internet.

I have a strong wifi connection but Firefox tells me cannot find server at `start.unbuntu.com`

Comment: Can you ping google.com?

Comment: No i cannot - i've tried installing updates using update-manager but it keeps telling me to check network / internet connection.  Although network manager say connection good.

Comment: Can firefox go to any website?

Comment: Firefox does not connect with any website.  Cannot ping google.  Wifi properties shows good connection.

Answer (score 2):

You've made a typo.

It's **Ubuntu** not Unbuntu.

 This is the site: http://start.ubuntu.com/

Comment: that is an issue, but he also seems to not have any internet.

Comment: Yes... I've realised that from the comments on his question.